# Rails - Accessing one to many variables in a table loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a simple one to many relationship between tasks and priorities.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :subject, :body, :priority_id, :company_id, :status_id, :user_ids
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    belongs_to :priority
    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :status
end


class Priority < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
    has_many :tasks
end
```

From my tasks/show.html.erb view

```
<%= @task.priority.name %>
```

This works.

However in my tasks/index.html.erb

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= task.subject %></td>
    <td><%= task.body %></td>
    <td><%= task.priority.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', task %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

The call to task.priority.name does not work.

It throws a NoMethodError.

I'm guessing this is a really stupid newbie mistake but I can't for the life of me figure it out. It would have assumed that the Active Record magic would have filtered down into a look like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your NoMethodError comes on nil:NilClass. Try:

```
  <%= task.priority.name if task.priority %>
```

Comment: excellent guess Christoph! many thanks - I guess when you are newbie you doubt your syntax and don't think of simple things like this :) much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have well created all the models and links with primary keys in your database? I think you link to a task with a priority id (prority_id) which doesn't exists.

Check your datas.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is no validation of the presence of priority in task, it's quite possible that you are calling "name" on nil. Validate the presence of priority (with validates_presence_of) or check it exists before printing it as Christoph says.